# Javascript FinishMessage hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a bump and wondered if you could help me.

So the problem is that i found a JavaScript on the internet for a countdown timer, and in that  code there's a line that writes a message to the user when the timer expires.
How can i hyperlink that text in the JavaScript code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
                TargetDate = "8/12/2013 4:07 PM";
               // TargetDate = "9/1/2013 12:00 PM";
                BackColor = "transparent";
                ForeColor = "#36c228";
                CountActive = true;
                CountStepper = -1;
                LeadingZero = true;
                DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, \n<br /> %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
                FinishMessage = echo "<a href="#">Klikni ovde da odes na sajt!</a>"
                </script>
```

I am new to this so tried like that and guess what it's not working. I know that wouldn't work but had to try it. :)

If someone can help me i would appreciate it very much!

Comment: See http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/04/jquery-countdown-scripts.html

Comment: I just need this to work somehow, or change something to it to be able to work. i dont want another design i made my own. :)
FinishMessage = "<a href="#">Klikni ovde da odes na sajt!</a>"

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error there - Remove the Speech marks at the end (the following will open the link in a new window)

Should look like;

```
FinishMessage = echo <a href="#" target="_blank" >Klikni ovde da odes na sajt!</a>
```

Comment: Still not working... :(

In the javascript file there is only this connected to that var
`if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined")
  FinishMessage = "";`

Btw if that var isn't setup correctly the whole code is not working, it messes the whole timer...